# jquery - customEasing not working

Tags: jquery, animation

Everything works nicely in my script below EXCEPT for the customEasing setting, which does not seem to do anything at all. I am calling:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

...but can't for the life of me figure out why the customEasing setting doesn't respond.

Thanks!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#menu-home').fadeIn(function(){ $(this).animate({"left" : "-5px"}, {duration:1500, customEasing:{"left":"easeInExpo"}}); });    
        $('#menu-concerts').fadeIn(function(){ $(this).delay(150).animate({"left" : "-5px"}, {duration:1500, customEasing:{"left":"easeInElastic"}}); });    
        $('#menu-bio').fadeIn(function(){ $(this).delay(300).animate({"left" : "-5px"}, {duration:1500, customEasing:{"left":"easeInOutCubic"}}); });    
        $('#menu-contact').fadeIn(function(){ $(this).delay(1050).animate({"left" : "-5px"}, {duration:1500, customEasing:{"left":"easeInOutQuint"}}); });    
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle? have you tried to pass duration as first parameter of fadeIn function?

Comment: I tried to make a fiddle (I had never done this before), but could not seem to get it to work... still, the relevant code is on display: http://jsfiddle.net/PaulCCC/t5Y8L/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your syntaxt is way to overcomplicated.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('#menu-home').animate({
        left : -5
    }, 1500, "easeInExpo");

    $('#menu-concerts').delay(150).animate({
        left : -5
    }, 1500, "easeInElastic");

    $('#menu-bio').delay(300).animate({
        left : -5
    }, 1500, "easeInOutCubic");

});
```

**IMPORTANT!!!**

You need to include **jquery-ui** script AFTER jquery. Without it, animation easing won't work.

Comment: Thanks a million for your help (and your much nicer code).